# Restrict access to accounts in account manager android

Tags: android, accountmanager

i hav an application which puts an account into android account manager. i know that account manager is a central repository shared by all apps. But i dont want other apps to access my account info through account manager. Is there any permissions or methods or any workarounds which can be used to achieve this ?

Comment: have u checked my answer?

Comment: yes.. but what i want is to do it programmatically from the device itself

Answer (score 0):

For that u have to run the following from the command line to clear out all account grants on the system.

For the emulator:

```
adb -e shell 'sqlite3 /data/system/accounts.db "delete from grants;"'
```

For a device (must be rooted and have the sqlite3 binary installed):

```
adb -d shell 'echo sqlite3 /data/system/accounts.db \"delete from grants\;\" | su'
```

here 'su' is the SUPERUSER

regards